# In SecureSocial what are the UserService implementation requirements?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1, securesocial

I wonder what exactly is required when providing an implementation of UserService. In the `InMemoryUserService.scala` example the `Identity` objects are saved as is, but is it possible to only save a subset of the fields?

For instance, what are the consequences of not saving `oAuth1Info` / `oAuth2Info` (like in [this implementation](https://github.com/leon/securesocial/blob/slick-demo/samples/scala/slick/app/models/User.scala))? In my case the only thing I would need is a unique `id: Int` per user that is passed to my application whenever a user is logged in.

Comment: You are not forced to follow any guidelines. You are free to implement what fits your context, thus in your case, save only fields you need from SocialUser (Identity) object. Personally, I totally rewrote the secure social API in order to fit my needs ;) without boring with any `Identity` default interface; just my own elements, to make things cleaner.

Comment: Ok, I think this is also what I will end up doing. The [documentation](http://securesocial.ws/guide/user-service.html) is not very clear on this point, and I don't really have time to dive into the source... Is your rewritten API open source?

Comment: It's not open source for now, but I envisage it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's up to you what you need to save. SecureSocial gives you all the information it can retrieve from the different providers.  When you load it back from your UserService implementation then that object is passed onto your SecuredActions.  The module only "passes" the object.

So, if you don't need the oAuthInfo fields just don't save them.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP question: what are the requirements.  It only answers part of the question: oAuthInfo fields are not required. What about PasswordInfo?  What about UserId?  What about firstName, lastName, etc.?  And what about the parts of the PasswordInfo, like the salt, hasher, etc..  It seems there's a lot more that is _required_, and it is unclear to me which fields are required.